# How to distribute free space between <table> columns evenly?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to make my html table to take the full window width in a way that `th` elements content does not overlap + there are even spacing between column headings (see the picture).
The space must scale with window width up to 0 (all words are hugging each other). How to do it?

big screen example:

[image: big screen]

small screen example:

[image: small screen]

By default the spacing between `th` elements gets proportional to the width of the elements.

If I use `table-layout: fixed` the width of the columns will be equal, i.e. space between them unti-proportional to width.

P.S. I need to use `border-spacing: 0` because I need to highlight full table rows and with positive `border-spacing` the table background will be visible inbetween cells.
P.P.S. the question is specifically about table layout. I know I can do anything with grid and flex box, but I'm trying to use right tags for right content, and in this case I have a table data, i.e. the solution should work with "display: table".

```css
table {
  width: 80%;
  background: gray;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

.auto {
  background: #90EE90;
}

.fixed {
    table-layout: fixed;
  background: #ADD8E6;
}
```

```html
<table class="auto">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>1</th>
<th>333</th>
<th>999999999</th>
<th>22</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>aa</td>
<td>aa</td>
<td>aa</td>
<td>aa</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table class="fixed">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>1</th>
<th>333</th>
<th>999999999</th>
<th>22</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>aa</td>
<td>aa</td>
<td>aa</td>
<td>aa</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `th {width: 25%;}` ?

Comment: To be really sure to understand what your goal is exactly, a picture might be helpful in this case

Comment: @A.Meshu, I can't imagin it working. how does it relate to space InBetween words?

Comment: @klm123 can you add a picture of the desired outcome?

Comment: @Corrl, added      .

Comment: `border-spacing:1em 0em;` can take 2 values (rows are sticked but columns appart of 1em each) , not sure i understand your trouble . :)

Comment: You can use bootstrap 5 to style the table, and use gutters

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I understand the border-spacing shouldn't be set fixed, but the way, that it automatically grows and fills the available space (which I think is not possible with border-spacing)

Comment: @BeerusDev are bootstrap gutter set with a fixed size or do they adapt to available space?

Comment: @klm123 must it be css only? Otherwise I think maybe setting the padding proportionally  inside tds could work?

Comment: unfortunately, i believe there is nothing alike space-evenly /between + 1gap for the last column in CSS for the table-layout display. border-spacing + padding-right would be the closest lookalike CSS trick you could use.

Comment: @Corrl Per the bootstrap documentation `Gutters can be responsively adjusted. Use breakpoint-specific gutter classes to modify horizontal gutters, vertical gutters, and all gutters.` [Gutters - Bootstrap v5.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/)

Answer (score 2):

A probably a bit hacky only css solution would be to insert empty th/td elements and give them a realive width of 100% / amount of filled columns. Here 4 columns -> gap-width: 25% (use calc() if odd amount)

```css
table {
  width: 80%;
  border-spacing: 0
}
th {
  text-align: left;
}
th,
td {  
  border: 1px solid teal;
}

.gap {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th class="gap"></th>
        <th>333</th>
        <th class="gap"></th>
        <th>999999999</th>
        <th class="gap"></th>
        <th>22</th>
        <th class="gap"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>aa</td>
        <td class="gap"></td>
        <td>aa</td>
        <td class="gap"></td>
        <td>aa</td>
        <td class="gap"></td>
        <td>aa</td>        
        <td class="gap"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```